# How can I show multiple UIViews by accessing their isHidden property?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I want to show multiple UIViews in a collection cell based on the logic statements below.

This function is for a Calendar view in my tabbar application. I'm reading events from a database on Firebase Firestore and saving it in `calData`.

```
func configureEventDotFor(cell: CalendarCell, cellState: CellState) {
    let dateString = self.globalFormatter.string(from: cellState.date)
        for event in self.calData.events! {
        let eventDateString = self.globalFormatter.string(from: event.startDate)
        if dateString != eventDateString {
            cell.holidayBar.isHidden = true
            cell.birthdayBar.isHidden = true
            cell.defaultBar.isHidden = true
        } else if event.category == "birthday" {
                cell.birthdayBar.isHidden = false
        } else if event.category == "holiday" {
                cell.holidayBar.isHidden = false
        } else if event.category == "default" {
            cell.defaultBar.isHidden = false
        } else {
            return
        }
    }
}
```

There are four events in `calData`, 2 default, 1 holiday, and 1 birthday. The birthday and holiday events are on the same day and therefore both `birthdayBar` and `holidayBar` should be visible for that day. I also expect to see a `defaultBar` for the other two events however only the holidayBar is visible when I run the app.

Comment: Can you try resetting each cell before you enter the if else block? This would ensure that each cell is refreshed when being requeued

Comment: just setting each view to be hidden?

Comment: yeah try doing that at first. Other than that I don't see any problems

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it did not change anything

Comment: Maybe upload full code example?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you appear to be trying to mess directly with the subviews of the cells of a UICollectionView. Don't do that. Just have the shown/hidden state of each subview be set in the `cellForItemAt` method, based on some easily accessible state (typically the contents of your data model). If the state changes, simply reload the collection view.

Comment: so this function gets called from my `cellForItemAt` method, does that not work?

Comment: I don’t know. You seemed to have a question so presumably something is not working.